# 2011 Chevy Traverse alternator problems

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, troubleshooting, alternator

I have a 2011 Chevy traverse.  I Went to O'rielly's and had an alternator tested.  They said voltage regulator failure.  Had the alternator changed out.  Still showing at a different O'rielly's regulator failure.  Just trying to figure out what is going on with it.  Please help.

Comment: What's Orielys? Do you mean O'Reilly, the  auto parts store?

Answer (score 2):

It could just be you got a bad alternator from O'Reilly's. Have them replace the unit for free. With re-manufactured parts, it happens. Have then test the new unit in the store before you leave to ensure you don't have to do it again.

Comment: I bought a starter from them, paid for the better quality one too. Spent hours diagnosing why it didn't work (bad relay?, bad ground?, bad wires?, etc.) only to find out the starter was defective off the shelf. I will never again leave the parts store without having them test.